# Fancybox and Nivo slider on one page not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, nivo-slider

I want to implement a simple Nivo slideshow in the banner of my site and a fancybox gallery below it - I just can't get them to work simultaneously. The Nivo slider takes preference, when I disable it, the fancybox gallery works. I am using fancybox v2 (jquery 1.7.2) and nivo slider jquery 1.7.1 - is that the problem? My jquery and js skills are seriously rudimentary, so please spell it out for me - thank you so much!
Here is the test site: http://designasite.co.za/aerialphotographer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try cleaning up your jQuery, give this a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();

        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            animSpeed: 1000, // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        });

    });
</script>
```

Also, delete the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Above where your current nivo slider plugin is being included and initialised and also move the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

into your `head` tag along with your other included files.

The reason for this is that you should only include jQuery once and use only one version on a page aswell and it's good practise to include all your plugins and css files at the same time, it's usually recommended to actually include your jQuery plugins at the bottom of your page so that it doesn't slow down your initial page from loading but wherever you have it, keep them together in the same place so that they are easier to find.

Comment: martincarlin87.... you are a rock star of heroic and epic proportions! Thank you so much, that did the trick! In addition to your suggestions i just had to change 1.7.1 to 1.7.2 for the Nivo slider and now it works perfectly. A kazillion thank you's... seriously!

Comment: no problem - it's not often I am right about answering on here! Also, to make your page load even faster you can use the CDN hosted jQuery version of your choice, e.g. - `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: OK I'm going to have to do some research on CDN - I have NO idea what that is :D

Comment: @Carin: CDN just means Content Delivery Network, so imagine every website using jQuery used the CDN one - it would already be in the user's cache meaning they don't need to download it again when they visit your website, or if they don't have it in their cache it will be faster to download the CDN version (probably) than on your site as the servers the jQuery is hosted on are a lot faster.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you for explaining it, and the advice! And thanks again for saving me yesterday :D

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with Nivo Slider and SigPro gallery (until I selected a version that didn't rely on the same jQuery code). I believe Nivo slider alters some of how the jQuery works and becomes incompatible with other image manipulation mods/plugins quite easily.

My recommendation would be to simply try another piece of gallery software, or a different piece of slideshow software. Or, don't have both on the same page at all.

A well known an unloved part of Nivo.

Comment: i always thought this was the case, but then I googled and it seemed that some people were getting it to work... check it out, the solution below works!!!