# Fancybox Not Working With Rhinoslider

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My site http://www.belovedstreets.org/test.html has a working Rhinoslider that shows a linked image first and then shows some DIV content.  The DIV content has several Fancybox clicks (the stars and the text in the banner) - See http://www.belovedstreets.org/home.html for how its supposed to work.

When in the Rhinoslider, everything appears properly, but the Fancybox stuff doesn't work at all.

I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813209/fancybox-and-nivo-slider-on-one-page-not-working) other help page and tried some stuff... but I still can't seem to get mine to work.

Hopefully its an easy fix?

Comment: it's working with FF, how can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: First part of the solution was to remove the old jquery min file (you can only have one).  Second part was ensuring that the new jquery min file was loaded before anything else related to jquery. 


I didn't realize that order mattered when loading the files.

All is well now.

Thanks.